# Custom Map Annotation

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, mkannotation

I have made all my pins have a reusable image as their image, however i do not want the users location's pin to have this image, i just want the default blue circle. Is there a way i can do this? Below is the code i use to create the custom image for the pin.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Drops")
    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "annotationPin")
   let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
   annotationView.transform = transform
    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: if annotation.isEqual(mapView.userLocation) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Return `nil` if annotation is `MKUserLocation`.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    ...
}
```